# How to get the Y-Coordinate of the cluster center?

Tags: python, opencv, k-means

I read about the K-Means clustering available with OpenCV. The function returns the cluster labels, cluster centers and the overall compactness of the cluster.

The centers are X-coordinates. How do I get the Y-Coordinates of the cluster center?

This is what I did to cluster objects.

```
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)

compactness,labels,centers = cv2.kmeans(np.float32(x_coord_list), 6, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
```

But it returns the centers as :

```
        [[646.8723  ]
     [111.409096]
     [803.1395  ]
     [495.14545 ]
     [235.57547 ]
     [349.85315 ]]
```

How could I get the Y-Coordinate?

Comment: is `x_coord_list` 1d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you are calling `cv2.kmeans` with only the x coordinates of your data points.

Assuming you also have a list `y_coord_list` representing the y coordinates of your points, you can use:

```
# Z contains both coordinates, one per row as specified by the documentation
Z = np.vstack((x_coord_list, y_coord_list))
# convert Z to np.float32
Z = np.float32(Z)

compactness,labels,centers = cv2.kmeans(Z, 6, None, criteria, 10, cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
```

Comment: Is there a way to know the best number of clusters just using opencv?

Comment: Not that I know of. You may want to implement something like the [elbow method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering)) by yourself.